# Network connectivity interruptions on bridge in case a new device is added or removed

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, docker, bridge

I am currently tracking down a connectivity issues of docker containers on a custom bridge network, which I could reduce to the Linux network stack without docker being involved.

The situation that I am observing is the following: I have a bridge device, which is connected to the outer world using forwarding and masquerading (so the bridge does not contain the outgoing network interface of the host). This bridge is used to perform network operations by a long-running process, which is restricted to this bridge using network namespaces and veth devices (exactly what docker does internally). What we see is that every time a (virtual) network device is added to or removed from the bridge, the communication of the long-running process is interrupted.

In order to reproduce the behavior we see you can use the following code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# teardown
function cleanup {
    set +e
    brctl delif brtest vethtest0
    ip link del vethtest0
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -s 10.12.10.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0
    iptables -D FORWARD -i brtest -o enp0s31f6 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D FORWARD -o brtest -i enp0s31f6 -j ACCEPT
    ip link delete veth0
    ip link set down brtest
    brctl delbr brtest
    ip netns del test
}
trap cleanup EXIT

ip netns add test

brctl addbr brtest
ip addr add 10.12.10.1/24 dev brtest
ip link set up dev brtest

ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link set veth1 netns test
brctl addif brtest veth0
ip link set up dev veth0

ip netns exec test ip addr add 10.12.10.42/24 dev veth1
ip netns exec test ip link set up dev veth1
ip netns exec test ip route add default via 10.12.10.1 dev veth1

# change external interface name
iptables -A FORWARD -o brtest -i enp0s31f6 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i brtest -o enp0s31f6 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -s 10.12.10.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0

while true; do ip netns exec test python3 -c "import socket; socket.gethostbyname('example.org')" && echo success; sleep 1; done
```

This sets up the bridge, veth devices, network namespace and the iptables rules to replicate the network setup and simulates the long-running process by periodically performing (volatile) UDP DNS requests in a while loop.

When launching this script, all DNS requests should succeed and you should see `success` messages at a regular pace.

To simulate devices joining and leaving the bridge, you can start the following code in a second bash:

```sh
while true
do
    echo "next"
    ip link add vethtest0 type veth peer name vethtest1
    brctl addif brtest vethtest0
    sleep 2
    brctl delif brtest vethtest0
    ip link del vethtest0
    sleep 1
done
```

As soon as this is running, you can observe that DNS requests will be delayed frequently and some of them even fail. In a parallel pcap you would see that sometimes the UDP packages from the DNS lookup are not routed to the outside world, but instead end up at the bridge device without ever leaving the host system.

Can someone explain what is happening here and why adding and removing devices to a bridge results in the connectivity issues? How to avoid them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to the netdev mailing list of the Linux kernel, Ido Schimmel provided the important information to solve this mystery:

> The MAC address of the bridge ('brtest' in your example) is inherited
>   from the bridge port with the "smallest" MAC address. Thus, when you
>   generate veth devices with random MACs and enslave them to the bridge,
>   you sometimes change the bridge's MAC address as well. And since the
>   bridge is the default gateway sometimes packets are sent to the wrong
>   MAC address.